# Problem with: Crashed: com.apple.main-thread. I can't find where is problem

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics

I have problem with crash in App. I tried add "DispatchQueue.main.async" in multiple places, usually where elements (controls) of view is used. I tried replicate this error but I can't. Always work great, without crash. The same error I have on others Views where use a FilterViewController.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  TempApp                          0x102113194 FilterResult.parseSessionDataToFilter(session:) + 436 (FiltersViewController.swift:436)
1  TempApp                          0x1021191a8 partial apply for closure #1 in NewestViewController.viewDidAppear(_:) + 55 (NewestViewController.swift:55)
2  TempApp                          0x10207b154 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 4332024148 (<compiler-generated>:4332024148)
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x191829298 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x19182a280 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x19180c5b8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81 + 856
6  CoreFoundation                 0x191b70c30 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
7  CoreFoundation                 0x191b6b0e8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2480
8  CoreFoundation                 0x191b6a200 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
9  GraphicsServices               0x1a7ce7598 GSEventRunModal + 160
10 UIKitCore                      0x194433bcc -[UIApplication _run] + 1052
11 UIKitCore                      0x1944391a0 UIApplicationMain + 164
12 TempApp                          0x102036ab4 main + 16 (main.m:16)
13 libdyld.dylib                  0x191849588 start + 4
```

NewestViewController.swift

```
    import UIKit
    import ZJFlexibleLayout
    
    class NewestViewController: UIViewController {
    
        @IBOutlet weak var newestCollectionView: UICollectionView!
        @IBOutlet weak var navBar: UINavigationBar!
        
        let reusableCellName = "newPhotoCell"
        
        let model = OthersModel()
        
        var page: Int = 1
        var isLoadingMore: Bool = false
        var dataCollection:[NewPhoto] = [] {
            didSet {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.newestCollectionView.reloadData()
                self.newestCollectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            }
        }
        var newFilter: FilterResult? {
            didSet {
               self.loadNewData()
            }
        }
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let layout = ZJFlexibleLayout(delegate: self)
            
            self.newestCollectionView.delegate = self
            self.newestCollectionView.dataSource = self
            self.newestCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
            
            self.navBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)]
        }
        
        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
                if let currentUser:FotkaUser = Session.getCurrentUser() {
                        let filter = FilterResult()
                        filter.parseSessionDataToFilter(session: currentUser)
                        self.newFilter = filter
                }
        }
        
        func loadNewData() {
            self.page = 1
            self.loadData(page: self.page) { (photos) in
                if photos != nil {
                    self.dataCollection = photos!.photos
                }
            }
        }
        
        func loadNextPage() {
            self.loadData(page: self.page) { (photos) in
                if photos != nil {
                    self.dataCollection += photos!.photos
                }
            }
        }
        
        func loadData(page: Int, responseObj: @escaping (NewestPhotos?) -> Void) {
            let params = self.getParams(page: page)
            
            self.model.getLatestPhotos(params: params) { (newestPhotos, error) in
                if (error == nil) {
                                    if (newestPhotos.photos.count > 0) {
                                        self.page += 1
                                        self.isLoadingMore = false
                                        responseObj(newestPhotos)
                                    } else {
                                        self.isLoadingMore = true
                                        responseObj(nil)
                                    }
                } else {
                    self.isLoadingMore = true
                    responseObj(nil)
                }
            }
        }
        
        func getParams(page: Int) -> [String: String] {
            let params = self.newFilter!.getFilterParams(fullGender: true)
            let baseParams = ["page": "\(page)","limit": "20"]
            
            return params.merging(baseParams) { $1 }
        }
        
        @IBAction func runFilter(_ sender: Any) {
            let view = FiltersViewController.loadFromNib()
            view.setTypeFilter(type: .SEX_AGE_REGION)
            view.setDefaultFilter(filter: self.newFilter!)
            view.saveFilterInDB()
            view.onChange = { (filtr) in
                self.newFilter = filtr
            }
            let bottomSheetViewController = MDCBottomSheetController(contentViewController: view)
            present(bottomSheetViewController, animated: true)
        }
        
    }
    
    extension NewestViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return self.dataCollection.count
        }
        
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
            let data = self.dataCollection[indexPath.row]
            
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: self.reusableCellName, for: indexPath) as! NewPhotoCollectionViewCell
            
            cell.image.downloaded(from: data.urls.s300)
            
            return cell
        }
        
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let data = self.dataCollection[indexPath.row]
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .ShowProfile, object: nil, userInfo: ["login": data.login])
        }
        
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            
            if indexPath.row == (collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1) && !isLoadingMore {
                isLoadingMore = true;
                self.loadNextPage()
            }
        }
    }
    
    extension NewestViewController: ZJFlexibleDataSource {
        func sizeOfHeader(at section: Int) -> CGSize {
            return CGSize.zero
        }
        
        func sizeOfItemAtIndexPath(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
            let data = self.dataCollection[indexPath.row]
            return CGSize(width: data.w, height: data.h)
        }
        
        func numberOfCols(at section: Int) -> Int {
                return 2
        }
        
        func spaceOfCells(at section: Int) -> CGFloat{
            return 12
        }
        
        func sectionInsets(at section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
            return UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 12, bottom: 8, right: 12)
        }
        
        func heightOfAdditionalContent(at indexPath : IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
            return 0
        }
    }
```

FiltersViewCOntroller.swift

```
import UIKit
import SearchTextField

class FiltersViewController: BottomSheetContentViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var navigationTitle: UINavigationItem!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var ageSection: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var regionsSection: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationSection: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginSection: UIView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var sexButtonAll: CircleButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var sexButtonMale: CircleButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var sexButtonFemale: CircleButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var ageSlider: NMRangeSlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var regionsTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationTextField: SearchTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginTextField: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var rangeLocation: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ageRangeLabel: UILabel!
    
    var sexButtonColelction: [CircleButton] = []
    var regions: [RegionItem] = []
    var cities: [CityFinder] = []
    var selectedCity: CityFinder?
    var rangePicker:DownPicker?
    var session = Session.getCurrentUser()
    
    private var saveFilter: Bool = false
    
    var defaultFilter: FilterResult = FilterResult()
    
    let rangeData: [RagneSelector] = [
        RangeSelector(name: "Całe miasto", range: 1),
        RangeSelector(name: "+ 25 km", range: 25),
        RangeSelector(name: "+ 50 km", range: 50),
        RangeSelector(name: "+ 75 km", range: 75),
        RangeSelector(name: "+ 100 km", range: 100),
        RangeSelector(name: "+ 125 km", range: 125),
    ]
    
    var onChange: ((_ filter: FilterResult) -> Void)?
    
    private var type: FilterType = .SEX
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.initSections()
        self.initSex()
        self.initAgeSlider()
        self.initLocations()
        self.initRegions()
        self.initRangeLocation()
        
    }
    
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        switch type {
        case .SEX:
            self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 140)
            break;
        case .SEX_AGE:
            self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 200)
            break;
        case .SEX_AGE_REGION:
            self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 320)
            break;
        case .ALL:
            self.navigationTitle.title = "Szukaj"
            self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 400)
            break;
        }
    }
    
    func setTypeFilter(type: FilterType) {
        self.type = type
    }
    
    func setDefaultFilter(filter: FilterResult) {
        self.defaultFilter = filter
    }
    
    func saveFilterInDB() {
        self.saveFilter = true
    }
    
    func getCurrentSex() -> SexSelect {
        let activeSexButton = self.sexButtonColelction.first { $0.isSelect == true }
        
        switch activeSexButton?.tag {
        case 0:
            return SexSelect.ALL
        case 1:
            return SexSelect.MALE
        case 2:
            return SexSelect.FEMALE
        default:
            return SexSelect.ALL
        }
    }
    
    func getCurrentAgeRange() -> (from: Int, to: Int) {
        return (Int(self.ageSlider.lowerValue),Int(self.ageSlider.upperValue))
    }
    
    func getCurentRegion() -> [Int] {
        return self.regions.map { $0.id }
    }
    
    func getCurrentLocation() -> (name: String, id: Int)? {
        if self.selectedCity != nil {
            let id = Int(self.selectedCity!.id)
            return (name: self.selectedCity!.name, id: id!)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    func getCurrentLogin() -> String {
        return self.loginTextField.text!
    }
    
    func getRangeLocation() -> RangeSelector? {
        return self.rangeData.first { $0.name == self.rangeLocation.text }
    }
    
    func initSections() {
        self.sexButtonColelction = [sexButtonAll, sexButtonMale, sexButtonFemale]
        self.navigationTitle.title = "Filtruj"
        
        switch self.type {
        case .SEX_AGE:
            self.ageSection.isHidden = false
            break;
        case .SEX_AGE_REGION:
            self.regionsSection.isHidden = false
            self.ageSection.isHidden = false
            break;
        case .ALL:
            self.ageSection.isHidden = false
            self.loginSection.isHidden = false
            self.locationSection.isHidden = false
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    
    func initAgeSlider() {
        let defaultValues = self.defaultFilter
        self.ageSlider.minimumValue = 16
        self.ageSlider.maximumValue = 66
        self.ageSlider.stepValue = 1
        self.ageSlider.minimumRange = 3
        self.ageSlider.upperValue = Float(defaultValues.ageTo)
        self.ageSlider.lowerValue = Float(defaultValues.ageFrom)
        
        updateAgeLabels()
    }
    
    func initRangeLocation() {
        
        self.rangePicker = DownPicker(textField: self.rangeLocation, withData: self.rangeData.map { $0.name })
        self.rangePicker?.setToolbarDoneButtonText("OK")
        self.rangePicker?.setToolbarCancelButtonText("Anuluj")
        self.rangePicker?.setPlaceholder("Odległość...")
        
        self.rangeLocation.text = self.rangeData.first { $0.range == self.defaultFilter.locationRange }?.name
    }
    
    func initRegions() {
        let regionsCollection = RegionsPopupViewController.regionsList
        
        self.regions = (self.defaultFilter.region.map({ (item) -> RegionItem in
            return regionsCollection.first(where: { $0.id == item })!
        }))
        
        let regionsName = self.regions.map { $0.name }
        self.regionsTextField.text = regionsName.joined(separator: ", ")
    }
    
    func initSex() {
        let sexFilter = self.defaultFilter.sex
        
        switch sexFilter {
        case .MALE:
            self.sexButtonColelction[1].sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
            break
        case .FEMALE:
            self.sexButtonColelction[2].sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
            break
        case .ALL:
            self.sexButtonColelction[0].sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
            break
        }
    }
    
    
    func initLocations() {
        self.locationTextField.maxNumberOfResults = 5
        locationTextField.itemSelectionHandler = { filteredResults, itemPosition in
            let item = filteredResults[itemPosition]
            let selectedItem = self.cities.first { $0.name == item.title && $0.region == item.subtitle }
            if(selectedItem != nil) {
                self.selectedCity = selectedItem!
            }
            self.rangeLocation.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            self.locationTextField.text = item.title
        }
        
        self.locationTextField.userStoppedTypingHandler = {
            if let criteria = self.locationTextField.text {
                if criteria.count > 3 {
                    self.locationTextField.showLoadingIndicator()
                    
                    self.searchMoreItemsInBackground(criteria: criteria) { results in
                        self.locationTextField.filterItems(results)
                        self.locationTextField.stopLoadingIndicator()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        self.locationTextField.placeholder = "Miasto.."
        self.locationTextField.text = self.defaultFilter.location
        self.locationTextField.theme.cellHeight = 50
        self.locationTextField.theme.bgColor = .white
        self.locationTextField.theme.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14)
    }
    
    func searchMoreItemsInBackground(criteria: String, response : @escaping ([SearchTextFieldItem]) -> Void) {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .api
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        
        Api.apiRequest(withParams: "search/getCities", parameters: ["city": criteria], success: { (sessionTask, result) in
            
            do {
                let dataJson = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: result, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
                let decodable = try decoder.decode(GetCity.self, from: dataJson)
                let citiesList = self.getCityListObject(data: decodable)
                self.cities = decodable.cities
                response(citiesList)
            } catch {
                response([])
            }
            
        }) { (sessionTask, error) in
            response([])
        }
    }
    
    func getCityListObject(data: GetCity) -> [SearchTextFieldItem] {
        var searchList: [SearchTextFieldItem] = []
        
        for item in data.cities {
            searchList.append(SearchTextFieldItem(title: item.name, subtitle: item.region))
        }
        
        return searchList
    }
    
    func updateAgeLabels() {
        let maxValue = (Int(self.ageSlider.upperValue) > 65) ? "65+" : String(format: "%d",Int(self.ageSlider.upperValue))
        self.ageRangeLabel.text = String(format: "%d - %@", Int(self.ageSlider.lowerValue), maxValue)
    }
    
    func saveInDB() {
        let params = self.defaultFilter.getFilterParams(fullGender: true)
        Api.apiRequest(withParams: "user/filterSet", parameters: params) { (sessionTask, result) in
            self.session?.filterGenders = params["gender"] as! String
            Session.setCurrentUser(self.session)
        } failure: { (sessionTask, error) in
        }
    }
    
    func getCurrentFiltr() -> FilterResult {
        
        switch type {
        
        case .SEX:
            self.defaultFilter.sex = self.getCurrentSex()
            break;
        case .SEX_AGE:
            self.defaultFilter.sex = self.getCurrentSex()
            let currentAge = self.getCurrentAgeRange()
            self.defaultFilter.ageFrom = currentAge.from
            self.defaultFilter.ageTo = currentAge.to
            break;
        case .SEX_AGE_REGION:
            self.defaultFilter.sex = self.getCurrentSex()
            let currentAge = self.getCurrentAgeRange()
            self.defaultFilter.ageFrom = currentAge.from
            self.defaultFilter.ageTo = currentAge.to
            self.defaultFilter.region = self.getCurentRegion()
            break;
        case .ALL:
            self.defaultFilter.sex = self.getCurrentSex()
            let currentAge = self.getCurrentAgeRange()
            self.defaultFilter.ageFrom = currentAge.from
            self.defaultFilter.ageTo = currentAge.to
            let currentLocation = self.getCurrentLocation()
            if currentLocation != nil {
                self.defaultFilter.location = currentLocation!.name
                self.defaultFilter.locationId = currentLocation!.id
            }
            self.defaultFilter.locationRange = self.getRangeLocation()!.range
            self.defaultFilter.login = self.getCurrentLogin()
            break;
        }
        
        return self.defaultFilter
    }
    
    @IBAction func close(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    @IBAction func accept(_ sender: Any) {
        self.onChange!(self.getCurrentFiltr())
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        if (self.saveFilter) {
            self.saveInDB()
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func changeAge(_ sender: Any) {
        updateAgeLabels()
    }
    
    @IBAction func changeSex(_ sender: CircleButton) {
        self.sexButtonColelction.forEach { (item) in
            if (item == sender) {
                item.isSelect = true
            } else {
                item.isSelect = false
            }
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func onFocus(_ sender: Any) {
        let regionView = RegionsPopupViewController()
        regionView.setUserChoises(filter: self.defaultFilter)
        regionView.onSave = { regions in
            self.regions = regions
            self.defaultFilter.region = self.regions.map { $0.id }
            let regionsName = self.regions.map { $0.name }
            self.regionsTextField.text = regionsName.joined(separator: ", ")
        }
        let bottomSheetViewController = MDCBottomSheetController(contentViewController: regionView)
        self.present(bottomSheetViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

enum FilterType {
    case SEX
    case SEX_AGE
    case SEX_AGE_REGION
    case ALL
}

enum SexSelect {
    case MALE
    case FEMALE
    case ALL
}

class FilterResult {
    var sex: SexSelect = .ALL
    var ageFrom: Int = 18
    var ageTo: Int = 30
    var region: [Int] = [101]
    var location: String?
    var locationId: Int = 0
    var locationRange: Int = 0
    var login: String?
    
    private let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    init() {
    }
    
    func saveInApp() {
        let filter = self.getFilterParams(fullGender: true)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(filter["gender"]! as String, forKey: searchDefaultsKeys.sex)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.ageFrom, forKey: searchDefaultsKeys.ageFrom)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.ageTo, forKey: searchDefaultsKeys.ageTo)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.locationRange, forKey: searchDefaultsKeys.distance)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.locationId, forKey: searchDefaultsKeys.cityId)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.location, forKey: searchDefaultsKeys.cityName)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
    
    func readCustomFilter() -> Bool {
        let custom = userDefaults.integer(forKey: searchDefaultsKeys.customFilter)
        
        if(custom != 1) {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
    
    func loadFromApp() {
        
        if(!self.readCustomFilter()) {
            return
        }
        
        if let sex = userDefaults.string(forKey: searchDefaultsKeys.sex) {
            self.sex = self.getSexFromSession(sex: sex)
        }
        
        self.ageFrom = userDefaults.integer(forKey: searchDefaultsKeys.ageFrom)
        self.ageTo = userDefaults.integer(forKey: searchDefaultsKeys.ageTo)
        self.locationRange = userDefaults.integer(forKey: searchDefaultsKeys.distance)
        self.locationId = userDefaults.integer(forKey: searchDefaultsKeys.cityId)
        self.location = userDefaults.string(forKey: searchDefaultsKeys.cityName)
    }
    
    func parseSessionDataToFilter(session: FotkaUser) {
        self.sex = self.getSexFromSession(sex: session.filterGenders)
        self.ageFrom = session.ageStart.intValue
        self.ageTo = session.ageEnd.intValue
        if session.regions == "0" {
            self.region = [101]
        } else {
            let splitedRegions = session.regions.split(separator: ",")
            if (splitedRegions.count > 0) {
                self.region = splitedRegions.map { Int($0) ?? 0 }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func parseSessionDataToSearch(session: FotkaUser) {
        self.sex = self.getSexFromSession(sex: session.searchGender)
        self.ageFrom = Int(session.searchAgeStart)!
        self.ageTo = Int(session.searchAgeEnd)!
        self.locationRange = 1
        self.location = session.searchLocName
        self.locationId = Int(session.searchCityId) ?? 0
        
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(1, forKey: searchDefaultsKeys.customFilter)
        self.saveInApp()
    }
    
    private func getSexFromSession(sex: String) -> SexSelect {
        switch sex {
        case "all":
            return .ALL
        case "female":
            return .FEMALE
        case "male":
            return .MALE
        default:
            return .FEMALE
        }
    }
    
    func getFilterParams(fullGender: Bool) -> [String:String] {
        
        var gender = "all"
        var genderV2 = "all"
        switch self.sex {
        case .MALE:
            gender = "m"
            genderV2 = "male"
            break;
        case .FEMALE:
            gender = "k"
            genderV2 = "female"
            break;
        case .ALL:
            gender = "all"
            break;
        }
        return [
            "gender": (fullGender) ? genderV2 : gender,
            "ageStart": "\(self.ageFrom)",
            "ageEnd": "\(self.ageTo)",
            "regions": self.region.map{String($0)}.joined(separator: ",")
        ]
    }
    
    func getSearchParams() -> [String:String] {
        let baseParams = self.getFilterParams(fullGender: false)
        return [
            "plec": baseParams["gender"]!,
            "wiek_od": "\(self.ageFrom)",
            "wiek_do":"\(self.ageTo)",
            "odleglosc": "\(self.locationRange)",
            "miejscowosc_id": "\(self.locationId)",
            "login": self.login ?? ""
        ]
    }
}

struct searchDefaultsKeys {
    static let sex = "s.sex2"
    static let ageFrom = "s.ageFrom"
    static let ageTo = "s.ageTo"
    static let distance = "s.distance"
    static let cityId = "s.cityid"
    static let cityName = "s.cityName"
    static let customFilter = "s.customFilter2"
}

class RangeSelector {
    var name: String
    var range: Int
    
    init(name: String, range:Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.range = range
    }
}

class CircleButton: UIButton {
    
    var isSelect: Bool = false {
        willSet {
            if(newValue) {
                self.setActive()
            } else {
                self.unsetActive()
            }
        }
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setProperties()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setProperties()
    }
    
    func setProperties() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.unsetActive()
    }
    
    func setActive() {
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.fotkaBlue.cgColor
        self.setTitleColor(.fotkaBlue, for: .normal)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.fotkaBlueAlpha
    }
    
    func unsetActive() {
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        self.setTitleColor(.init(hexString: "222222"), for: .normal)
        self.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}
```

Comment: Line 436 corresponds in a line inside `parseSessionDataToFilter`? Which one?

Comment: Yes, you have the exact line where the crash happens: Line 436 in `FiltersViewController` inside the function `parseSessionDataToFilter(session: FotkaUser)`. I suspect that the `session` of type `FotkaUser` has some nil values inside, which you try to access in the function. Put a break on the start of this function, and try to `print sessions` in the debugger. See which value is nil. I might blindly guess that your `session.regions` is nil, but only you can know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The crash happens in `parseSessionDataToFilter(session:)` method, I would try to check if everything is correct there.

Answer (score 0):

check `NewestViewController`

```
if let currentUser:FotkaUser = Session.getCurrentUser() {
   let filter = FilterResult()
   filter.parseSessionDataToFilter(session: currentUser) // i think you might facing problem due to this line
   self.newFilter = filter
}
```